# Drop down menu for blogger with automatic link update

Tags: html, css, blog, blogger

My mom has a recipe blog in blogger which has many categories "Cakes", "Celebration Day" etc which are filled with numerous recipe posts. Now I want to organize my blog in a better way and make a drop down menu for all the categories(I already have labels) but I dont want to keep updating the menu whenever I include a new post. I want to have it updated automatically. Is there any way it can be done with CSS or html codes?

Comment: Could you please explain how you managed to do this? I am still struggling and could not understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement any one of [dozens of different drop down menu's](http://24work.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/17-featured-content-slider-for-blogger.html) in the template, but I have no idea if blogger will automatically populate them, I'd suggest the [blogger support forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/blogger) might be the best place to ask.

Comment: I thought I'll just have to keep using those labels but I found a better alternative in installing a new page 'Table Of Contents' which automatically updates the new posts.Thanks for the help.